PySpark: Throwing error 'Column' object is not callable while using .count()
I'm working with a PySpark DataFrame and trying to count the number of null values in each column. I tried the following expression:
[col(c).isNull().count() for c in df.columns]

throws error:
----> 2 [col(c).isNull().count() for c in df.columns]
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

On the other hand, this expression works without any issue:
[df.filter(col(c).isNull()).count() for c in df.columns]

Output:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 109, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I’m confused about why the first expression fails while the second one works. Could someone explain the difference between the two and why the error occurs in the first case?

The mistake in Expresion 1 is it is calling count() on a Column object, which is not allowed.
In Expression 2, count() is being called on the filtered DataFrame, which is the correct usage.
